# Using scanner and multi variable arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

So, I have this tiny problem. I'm prompting the user to input 3 variables (Str, Str, Int) that need to be stored in a multi variable array and I can't get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
LibraryBook[] book = new LibraryBook[5];

//inputing a new book
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
LibraryBook[] myBook = new LibraryBook[0];

System.out.println("Enter book name: ");
String title = input.nextLine().trim();
System.out.println("Enter author name: ");
String author = input.nextLine().trim();

System.out.println("Enter # pages: ");
int pages = input.nextInt();

myBook[0] =new LibraryBook(title,author,pages);
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at LibraryBookSort.main(LibraryBookSort.java:36)
```

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete this line

```
LibraryBook[] myBook = new LibraryBook[0];
```

and replace last line

```
myBook[0] =new LibraryBook(title,author,pages);
```

by this

```
book[0] =new LibraryBook(title,author,pages);
```

Comment: @ClaudiaBenitezdeArmstrong If it worked, the please click on the tick mark on left to this answer so that it will be marked accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your array with zero size, so you basically don't have any space to store a variable (a class in your case). Here's the correction:

```
LibraryBook[] myBook = new LibraryBook[10];
```

I'm assuming you will need no more than 10 locations in your program.

Edit: I just noticed you have two LibraryBook arrays declared, but you're only using one. Is there a necessity for the unused one?

Comment: Yes. I have 9 existing books, I have to add a new one and then sort them. It works now, thanks!

Comment: I just edited my question, in case you haven't noticed already.

Comment: No, it was a mistake. I wasn't sure how to store the inputed information and wrote that line twice.